# Is there a way to send raw Bluetooth data to a specific UUID

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to send Bluetooth data to a specific UUID. By 'raw' data I have the hex values of the bytes I want to send and the UUID address of the device I want to send them to, but am unsure as to if there exists any software that aids in transmitting raw data. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Aby data you send to BLE device is RAW data.